# Oracle sql join against multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables that contain together a complete set of data that has been imported into my database through an application function.
I want to compare this data against another table (exam_import) that was used to perform the import.  But I keep getting duplicate records.

- Table 1 contains my import list. `exams_import ip`
- Table 2 contains my exams      `exams e`
- Table 3 contains my students   `students s`
- Table 4 contains my Student ID's  `student_ids i`

What I want is this

```
select s.student_name, i.my_student_id, e.exam_no, e.exam_descrip
from exams e
left join exams_import ip on ip.exam_no = e.exam_no
left join students s on s.student_db_uid = e.student_db_uid
left join student_ids i on s.internal_id = i.dbid
```

The result table should show my imported exams as they are seen in the database with student name and assigned ID.
But I seem to be getting several duplicates where the student ID has been changed from the imported list.

```
Student_Name    my_Student_ID   Exam No     Exam description

 1. Smith^David    12345        123         English_101 
 2. Smith^Bill     12346        124         English_101
 3. Jones^John     12789        225         Maths_201 
 4. Roberts^Stan   12885        ***456***   English_101
 5. Roberts^Stan   12885$$$1       ***456***   English_101
 6. Tripp^Malcolm  20144        566         English_101
```

One student may have many exams.  Each exam number is unique.  There should be one record per exam number displayed.  See bolded output showing replicated record.
Student should only have a new unique ID with a $$$ suffix assigned by application if matching rules have not been met.  Otherwise they retain the imported ID.

**Sample data**

```
Exams Table  
 exam_no, exam_desc,    Student_db_uid, exam_date,   
 123    English_101     1001        15-02-2015  
 124    English_101     1002        15-02-2015  
 225    Maths_201       1003        16-02-2015  
 456    English_101     1004        15-02-2015  
 566    English_101     1005        15-02-2015  
 666    Science_101     1006        14-02-2015 

Students Table  
student_name,   internal_id, Student_db_uid, DOB  
Smith^David     2001        1001    10-01-94  
Smith^Bill      2002        1002    25-02-94  
Jones^John      2003        1003    19-12-94    
Roberts^Stan    2004        1004    16-12-93  
Tripp^Malcolm   2005        1005    12-09-94   
Roberts^Stanley 2006        1006    16-12-93

Student ID
my_student_id, internal_id, Student_db_uid, alt_id
12345       2001    1001    null  
12346       2002    1002    null  
12789       2003    1003    null  
12885       2004    1004    null  
12885$$$1   2006    1006    null  
20144       2005    1005    null  

Exams_import  
Student_id, student_name, exam_no, exam_desc, exam_date, DOB  
12345 Smith^David   123 English_101 15-02-2015 10-01-94  
12346 Smith^Bill    124 English_101 15-02-2015 25-02-94  
12789 Jones^John    225 Maths_201 16-02-2015 19-12-94  
12885 Roberts^Stan  456 English_101 15-02-2015 16-12-93  
20144 Tripp^Malcolm 566 English_101 15-02-2015 12-09-94  
12885 Roberts^Stanley 666 Science_101 14-02-2015 16-12-93
```

Comment: what are the records for Roberts^Stan in student and student id table?

Comment: There is only one entry in each table for that student.  Please note.  Data is fictitious and for example only.

Comment: Please provide sample data for all of the tables in your query

Comment: even if it is fictitious, you still need to give some sample input data for all tables and your output based on that. It is good that you came up with the query but without input data, it is difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: Why are you doing left joins instead of inner joins?

Comment: In the sample data `12885$$$1   2006    1006    null` this record doesn't match with your desired output `5. Roberts^Stan   12885$$$1       456  English_101`.  Can you please explain.

Comment: Thats the part I need help with.  The application has not matched the student to an existing record so applies the $$$, but my sql displays both patient ID's against the same exam record.